# Min() with INNER JOIN and Full-text-search

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join, min

So Ive got the following Query to work just fine, searching for '`test`*' in '`products_desc`' column and fetching all its prices in the '`prices`' table.

```
SELECT products.id, prices.price, products.product_desc FROM products
INNER JOIN prices
ON prices.product_id = products.id
WHERE 
MATCH (products.product_desc) AGAINST ('test*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Although the 'prices' table consists of multiple prices per product and **I only want to fetch the lowest one to each product**. I've previously filtered the prices using

```
INNER JOIN ( 
    SELECT min(price) as price, prices.product_number as product_number FROM prices 
    WHERE prices.product_number LIKE'".$q."%'
    GROUP BY prices.product_number
) min_prices
  on prices.price = min_prices.price 
  and prices.product_number = min_prices.product_number
```

but this was when I used products_numbers within the `prices` table (now there is just a product_id-column.

```
Products
id | product_desc
----------------------------------------
1  | product1
2  | product2  

Prices
id | product_id | price
------------------------------------------------
1  | 1          | 312
2  | 1          | 219 
3  | 2          | 312 
4  | 2          | 111
```

Also, the table consists of 10+ million rows so, efficiency matters a lot :)

**EDIT**

What if I need to access value of columns on the min(prices.price) row?

```
SELECT products.id, MIN(prices.price) as prices_price, prices.id as prices_id, products.product_desc, products.product_number, prices.supplier_id, suppliers.name FROM products
INNER JOIN prices
ON prices.product_id = products.id
INNER JOIN suppliers
ON prices.supplier_id = suppliers.id
WHERE 
MATCH (products.product_desc) AGAINST ('test*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
GROUP BY prices.product_id
```

The above returns the lowest price per product but also the wrong value in the other columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-handling.html) for this, with [MIN()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min) **group by** function.

**GROUP BY** is used to group values from a column, and perform calculations on column.

In our case we want to group the result by **product_id** as it's repeating in second table and perform calculation (**min()**) on price column of second table.

This is how your Query would look like:

```
SELECT products.id, MIN(prices.price), products.product_desc FROM products
INNER JOIN prices
ON prices.product_id = products.id
WHERE 
MATCH (products.product_desc) AGAINST ('test*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
GROUP BY prices.product_id
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is quite unefficient. The reponse time is 1.5sec, it used to be 0.05sec using my old Query.
product_desc is indexed.

Comment: hmm.. May be you can get all the rows first in sub query and then in outer query you can group by the product_id? I'm not sure if this will change the response time by good margin.

Comment: Well, stupid me. I noticed that the product_id wasn't indexed. Doing so reduced the reponse time to 0.00013 sec. Thanks alot though!

Comment: Oh I forgot about that, I thought if we're using JOINS columns must be indexed.

Comment: Did a little amendment to the post. :)

Comment: prices.id and prices.supplier_id.They get the first row's content but with the correct price. To simplify, I would like to fetch prices.* of the min(prices.price)-row :)